# Mac pkg installer distribution

Tags: macos, installation, dmg

I have build a flat package installer (meaning it is just a single pkg file) for Mac. Normally Mac installers are distributed inside a disk image (dmg) file. I know how to create a dmg file containing the pkg file, but I am wondering if this is necessary. Is there are reason why it is better to distribute the installer inside a disk image?

Answer (score 1):

Mac applications are often distributed as DMG, but that was mostly because Mac `.app` bundles are really a directory tree, not a single file. If you have a single-file `.pkg`, it is probably fine to distribute as-is.

*Note: in earlier versions of OS X this was true of .pkg also, but it has not been the case for some time, .pkg are now single file xar archives.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. pkg files are already compressed. I tried to zip it and the file size actually went up a bit!